# Is it possible to change a WPF RichTextBox's spelling error underline style?

Tags: .net, wpf, richtextbox

I hate the "puffy red-with-white-dots underline" that .NET's RichTextBox control (and probably the regular TextBox as well?) uses to highlight misspelled words - but I cannot figure out how to change it.

Can the style on this be changed, and if so, how?

Thanks!

Comment: This is only my opinion, but sometimes it is good to stick with a design you don't personally like because it has a clear meaning. Things like a floppy disk for saving, the "hamburger" menu for options, etc. This relieves some of the burden of having to explain your interface to your users. Just for example, if you used a green underline, people would assume it was a grammar error. Just a thought.

Comment: @Gray 100% agree that a consistent experience is preferred - I'm just hoping to make the line a little less thick - or maybe make it a thin, wavy red line like you often see in other textboxes (like in browsers) - anything to make it more palatable :)

Comment: It's not possible - and interestingly (IMO) I believe it's caused by a bug.  When I had to implement underline painting in WPF using an adorner I found my underlines looked like the spell checker's, and I had to find a workaround to get it to look right, unfortunately I can't remember the details.  All I can suggest is a 3rd party's spell checker like keyoti, devexpress etc

Comment: @JimW I think you may be right on all counts - 1) The 'style' of the line may not be as intended 2) Bug or not, there doesn't seem to be a way to restyle it 3) I found NHunspell via another post here on SO, and may use it to implement a custom spell check solution. Thx! (note: link to NHunspell in NuGet: http://www.nuget.org/packages/NHunspell/)